# Efficient algorithm for searching in database

Tags: database, mongodb, algorithm

I am working on a new project where I have 500k questions to be stored in database. Each time a student answers a question, that ques is marked under **visited** category for that specific user. Thus, what a student should see on main page is question that he has never visited. So, my problem is that if 10 questions are posted on the main page, then each question will have to be first matched with collection of the visited question, check whether they are in the list of visited question for that user and then get posted on the main page. How should I minimize the time required for such kind of requirement? or Is my algorithm inefficient?

Comment: You should use sessions for this. If the user completes the quiz, only then insert their answers to DB and calculate final score.

Comment: How do you store the information that one user answered a question?

Comment: @vivek_23... it is not a quiz of 10 questions. all ques are simply like questions u see on quora feed, one after the other. I mean if student has answered a question and next time if he logs in, he should not see that same question, instead only new questions.

Comment: @JollyRoger ... i maintain a collection where each user's answers are stored in an array. I mean each array related to the user store reference to the questions answered. Questions are stored in different collection.

Comment: @sine99 then it's just a simple select with a where NOT IN condition. Any reason to not show answered posts?

Comment: A `NOT IN` kind of query with 500k entries should take no more than a few milliseconds even on a development machine. Are you sure you need to optimize this? If it takes more than that maybe you should instead have a look at your data structure/index

Comment: @ChatterOne .... what if the student has answered 10k questions? will the query  [array of answered ques] NOT IN [500k ques] be efficient that too with 1000 students using platform at the same time

Comment: @vivek_23 ... that is the requirement. I wonder if it will be good to check NOT IN condition for large sized array of answered ques.

Comment: @sine99 Ok, you can do an inner join of questions table and user answered table based on question ID. Now, you can programmatically make a HashSet of answered question IDs and when looping your data of questions, skip those whose IDs are contained in the HashSet that you have.